# animate.css - How to make an animation after pageload

Tags: css

I use animate.css to fadeInDown and fadeInUp the element.

```
<h1 class="animated fadeInDown">text</h1>
<h5 class="animated fadeInUp">text</h5>
```

How to make this animations work after pageload?

Also I added

```
.preload * {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -ms-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
}     

 $(".loader").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $("#home").removeClass("preload");
    });
```

But this do not help.

Comment: This can help you? https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Your code here
})
```

try to surround your jquery with this so that code will work only after page is loaded

**EDIT:-**[Demo with Loader spinner and after load Animations](http://jsfiddle.net/rbb089e8/1/)

Comment: Okay you havent added that details in your question add these details with your current question answer is apt with your extra Details I suggest that you please add an jsfiddle example with problem you are currently facing so that it may be addressed directly

Comment: Are you trying to load these animations with delay or you want animation load one after another ?

Comment: I want this animations work, when I hide the loader.